# How to use Aggregate Function within Group By clause

Tags: sql

How to use an Aggregate Function within a GROUP BY clause like this?

```
SELECT VCH_DCOA_CODE, SUM(VCH_DEFINATION.VCH_CREDIT) AS Debit
FROM  VCH_DEFINATION 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6)
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using for your requirement?

Comment: `SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE , 0,6)` could resolve to multiple `VCH_DCOA_CODE`s which do you want shown?

Comment: This should work in MySQL, but fail in most other RDBMSs; the SELECT clause includes a field (VCH_DCOA_CODE) that is neither constant, aggregated or included in the group clause.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to display the `sum()` with the full `VCH_DCOA_CODE` but `group by` the substring value, so I am guessing that you want this:

```
SELECT v1.VCH_DCOA_CODE, v2.Debit
FROM VCH_DEFINATION v1
INNER JOIN
(
    select SUM(VCH_DEFINATION.VCH_CREDIT) AS Debit, SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6) Shortcode
    from VCH_DEFINATION
    group by SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6)
) v2
    on v1.SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6) = v2.Shortcode
```

The subquery will get the `SUM()` for each `SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6)` but then that will be displayed with each full `VCH_DCOA_CODE`

But, If you do not want to display the full `VCH_DCOA_CODE`, then you can just use the inner query to get the result:

```
 select SUM(VCH_DEFINATION.VCH_CREDIT) AS Debit, SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6) Shortcode
 from VCH_DEFINATION
 group by SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6)` to the `select` clause as below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6), SUM(VCH_DEFINATION.VCH_CREDIT) AS Debit
FROM  VCH_DEFINATION 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(VCH_DCOA_CODE, 0, 6)
```

Comment: I think the op wants to select the full VCH_DCOA_CODE